# Referenceing randomNumber from button1_Click method

Tags: c#

I am creating a game for my class project but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to transfer the randomNumber value to the button1_Click method. I've tried numerous ways ive found on here but none have worked. When I click the button I want it to automatically select a value out the dollarAmount array. I just need to be able to reference my randomNumber from the button1_Click then I'm sure it will work.

```
namespace __Deal_Or_No_Deal__
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string[] dollarAmount = new string[26] { "0.01", "1", "5", "10", "25",
            "50", "75", "100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "750", "1,000",
            "5,000", "10,000", "25,000", "50,000", "75,000", "100,000", "200,000",
            "300,000", "400,000", "500,000", "750,000", "1,000,000" };

        int[] priceIndexInBox = new int[26] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
            11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 };

        string outputText = "";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //private int randomNumber = 0;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(
                "Are you ready to play Deal or No Deal?",
                "Deal or No Deal",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            if (result == DialogResult.No)
            {
                this.Close();
            }

            //Generate the price in each box
            //when the game starts

            int numberOfValueSet = 0;

            Random rnd = new Random();
            //while (numberOfValueSet < 26) 
            {
                //Generate a random number: 
                int randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, 26);

                //if (Array.IndexOf(priceIndexInBox, randomNumber) == -1)
                //{
                //    //The random number is not is the priceIndex array 
                //    //Insert the random number to the array 
                //    priceIndexInBox[numberOfValueSet] = randomNumber;
                //    numberOfValueSet++;
                //}
            }
        }

        private void generateRandom()
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox[] boxes =
            {
                picOneCent, picOneDollar, picFiveDollar, picTenDollar,
                picTwentyFiveDollar, picFiftyDollar, picSeventyFiveDollar,
                picOneHundredDollar, picTwoHundredDollar, picThreeHundredDollar,
                picFourHundredDollar, picFiveHundredDollar, picSevenHundredFiftyDollar,
                picOneThousandDollar, picFiveThousandDollar, picTenThousandDollar,
                picTwentyFiveThousandDollar, picFiftyThousandDollar,
                picSeventyFiveThousandDollar, picOneHundredThousandDollar,
                picTwoHundredThousandDollar, picThreeHundredThousandDollar,
                picFourHundredThousandDollar, picFiveHundredThousandDollar,
                picSevenHundredFiftyThousandDollar, picOneMillionDollar
            };

            int numberOfValueSet = 0;
            priceIndexInBox[numberOfValueSet] = randomNumber;
            string outputText = dollarAmount[randomNumber];

            blackBox.Text = "You have just picked case #" + (sender as Button).Text + 
                            " with $" + outputText + " random: " + randomNumber;

            boxes[randomNumber].Visible = false;
            Button buttonSelected = sender as Button;
            buttonSelected.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate some help in figuring this out. Thank you :)

Comment: I've tried to declare the randomNumber variable outside of the Form Load method but everytime I click the button I just get 0. so it chooses $0.01 every time.

Comment: Uncomment the `randomNumber` declaration which is outside the function `private int randomNumber = 0;` and _**make sure**_ when you are setting it in your function, you _don't initialize_ a new integer i.e in `int randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, 26)` please remove `int`

Comment: Your randomNumber is out of the button1_Click scope. You need a property or a member in the class scope to make it accessible or you may pass it in the button1_Click EventArgs parameter by for example extending the EventArgs class and then casting it. If you're not familiarized with this because maybe you're starting OO programing now, just use the scope solution.

Comment: Your 'Random' should be instantiated using some seed value. Common practice is to use milliseconds like so 'var random = new Random(DateTime.Now.TotalMilliseconds)' so each time you instantiate it it's very unlikely that you'll get the same set of random numbers.

Comment: That fixed a lot of it. I moved 'randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, 26)' into the button method so it changes everytime its clicked the number changes. But now the number will repeat sometimes so not all the dollarAmounts are chosen. @degant

Comment: @TitanBuilder1 that's okay. That's just how `Random` works, it doesn't promise returning all numbers before repeating. Run it about a 100-200 times and you might get all 26 matches :)

Comment: @degant my program looks kind of like the one below. I run out of buttons before all 26 matches are used so not all labels on the side can be chosen. https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSmThpCgWTqrIW9ZWYpL197S4QjTWUnwKfWjbzcQDYiPsa12gNb

Comment: @TitanBuilder1; If you have received an answer to your question, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem you have alluded to in comments is that you want to *randomize the order of the buckets*.

If the buckets are in random order then you can just iterate through them in the usual order, 0 through 26, and they'll be shuffled.

What you're doing here is called an "XY problem" on StackOverflow. You have some idea of how to solve your problem, you ask about *that idea*, and none of the answers actually address your *real problem*. Let's address the real problem.

To randomize a small array, do this:

```
    static Random random = new Random();
    string[] dollarAmount = (new[] { whatever })
      .OrderBy(x => random.NextDouble())
      .ToArray();
```

I note that had you asked this question in the first place, *you almost certainly would have gotten bad advice*, because this question is asked *constantly* on this site and attracts low-quality answers.

In particular:

- Do not randomize by sorting on a guid. Guids are guaranteed to be *unique*, not *unsorted*.
- Do not randomize by giving a random comparator to a sort algorithm; comparators are required to be *consistent with a total order*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a new random number every time the button is pressed. If that is correct, define your random generator as a class-scoped variable then call 'next' each button push.

[EDIT] Untested and incomplete, and probably not even the best way - but this will get you started as to not having duplicates. (As commented, you still have to deal with click #27. )

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    var possibles = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5.....,26}
    // The rest of your code here

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int randomNumber = -1;
        while (randomNumber == -1)
        {
            randomNumber = possibles[rnd.Next(0, 25)];
            if randomNumber > 0
            {
                possibles[randomNumber] = -1;
            }
        }
        // Do something with the random number
```

Comment: awesome! I used this and it works now however it will use the same number multiply times. How can I make it so it wont reuse the number again?

Comment: @TitanBuilder1: Suppose you got your wish. What would happen on the 27th button press?

Comment: @TitanBuilder1 recreate your arrays removing the last selected dollarAmount[index] and priceIndexInBox[index]. Your randomvalue will then be set by randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, priceIndexInBox.Length-1);

Answer (score 0):

Two lines are giving you trouble:

First,

```
int randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, 26);
```

You have 26 boxes but you're actually looking at 27 numbers. You should only go from 0-25, not to 26. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Second,

```
if (Array.IndexOf(priceIndexInBox, randomNumber) == -1)
```

Array.IndexOf returns the index in the array which the **value** was found. Because of this, you're checking if you're array has a value somehwere of between 0-26. Discounting the first error I mentioned above (should be 0-25), this conditional will never be true, because you're always going to have 0-25 as members of your array and they only way they could be changed is in this impossible conditional. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx

Instead, you want to check and see if one contains the dollar value in your dollar amount array, such as this:

```
if(Array.IndexOf(priceIndexInBox,dollarAmmount[randomNumber]) == -1)
```

This will properly ensure that dollar values are not repeated. Make these changes and see if your program is giving you the expected behavior.

EDIT: Looking more thoroughly at your code now it appears there are several syntax and logical errors inside your button event. Remember that the assignment operator (=) assigns whats on the **right** to what's on the **left**. This isn't a mathematical equals; this operation only goes one way. Also, your always accessing the first index of your priceIndexInBox because you are setting numberOfValueSet to 0 right before using it as an index.  Then your setting the value in the first box (and always the first box) to randomNumber, which is going to be whatever random number was generated at the end of your Form_Load. In other words, whatever random number was originally generated there is going to be overridden.

Comment: I made those changes but I continue to get the same numbers. I'm left will 10-15 dollar values left over

Answer (score 0):

Seems that one of your problems is the scope. See, your randomNumber doesn't 'live' outside your Form1_Load method. What you want to do is to make it accessible across the other methods of your class, so, one solution is to make your class the direct owner of random number, and you re-use that instance to update its value. Like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int _randomNumber = 0;
    ...

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you ready to play Deal or No Deal?",
    "Deal or No Deal",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
    MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
       this.Close();
    }

    //Generate the price in each box when the game starts
    int numberOfValueSet = 0;

    Random rnd = new Random();
    //while (numberOfValueSet < 26) 
    {
        //Generate a random number: 
        _randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, 26);

        //if (Array.IndexOf(priceIndexInBox, randomNumber) == -1)
        //{
        //    //The random number is not is the priceIndex array 
        //    //Insert the random number to the array 
        //    priceIndexInBox[numberOfValueSet] = randomNumber;


        //    numberOfValueSet++;
        //}
    }
}
```

See, in Form1_Load do not write int randomNumber, just re-use your class instance of it by just writing

```
_randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, 26);
```

Also, read some of the comments if you're worried about the correctness of random numbers generation